# Nagios: real-time logfile monitoring with nsca on linux

Tags: nagios

According to this article http://blog.medin.name/2012/03/20/real-time-event-log-monitoring-with-nsclient/

I succeccful used nsclient++ to push Windows Eventlog to a nagios server whenever a new eventlog produced.

But I didn't find a solution to do the same thing on linux.

I tried to use nsca, inotify and check_log plugin to do this.

But it didn't work.

Check_log plugin just got the summary of logfile, but i want to call send_nsca whenever a new line produced.

Any advices would be most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NSCA for log processing is a bit of overkill.

It would be much easier to set up rsyslog to send logs to a central location, and have Nagios check that. (You can also use [eventlog-to-syslog](http://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/) to achieve this on Windows.)

The stock check_log plugin is miserable; it parses the entire log file on every run, and uses *diff* to compare. Consol Labs has a much better [check_logfiles plugin](http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_logfiles/).

Be sure to read about [volatile services](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/volatileservices.html), too.